# How to get top level elements as well as one level down array elements aggregate in one mongo query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 mongo aggregate queries that work well separately -

```
   db.transfer_orders.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "request_timestamp": { $gte: ISODate("2017-10-00T00:00:00.000Z") },
            "request_timestamp": { $lt: ISODate("2017-10-12T00:00:00.000Z") },
            "purpose": "POSITIONING"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            to_count: { $sum: 1 },
            qty: { $sum: "$quantity"  } 
        }  
    },
    {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "to_count": "$to_count",
      "qty": "$qty"
    }
  }
])
```

and

```
    db.transfer_orders.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
            "request_timestamp": { $gte: ISODate("2017-10-00T00:00:00.000Z") },
            "request_timestamp": { $lt: ISODate("2017-10-12T00:00:00.000Z") },
            "purpose": "POSITIONING"
        }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$adjustments"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      totalChangeQty: { $sum: "$adjustments.change_in_quantity"}
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "adjusted_quantity": "$totalChangeQty"
    }
  }
])
```

The first query returns aggregate data of elements at the top level of the document, { "to_count" : 7810, "qty" : 19470 }

The second query returns aggregate data of elements at one level below the top level for the "adjustments" array - { "adjusted_quantity" : -960 }

Is there a way to write this as one query that will return both sets of data since the match criteria is the same for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following aggregate operation should suffice since it has a pipeline after the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** step that introduces the new field `adjusted_quantity`. This is made possible using the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#use-in-project-stage)** which returns the sum of the specified list of expressions for each document.

Once it reaches the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** stage, you can retain the value using the **[`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#use-in-group-stage)** operator.

```
db.transfer_orders.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "request_timestamp": { "$gte": ISODate("2017-10-00T00:00:00.000Z") },
            "request_timestamp": { "$lt": ISODate("2017-10-12T00:00:00.000Z") },
            "purpose": "POSITIONING"
        }
    },
    { 
        "$addFields": {
            "adjusted_quantity": {
                "$sum": "$adjustments.change_in_quantity"
            }    
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "to_count": { "$sum": 1 },
            "qty": { "$sum": "$quantity"  },
            "adjusted_quantity": { "$sum": "$adjusted_quantity" } 
        }  
    }
])
```

Comment: I get this result when I run the above query - { "_id" : null, "to_count" : 7810, "qty" : 19470, "adjusted_quantity" : 0 }

Comment: chridam - "adjustments" is an array that contains elements like this - ` "adjustments" : [
  {
   "adjustment_id" : "113179",
   "new_quantity" : 0,
   "change_in_quantity" : -1,
   "created_by" : "WMS",
   "event_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-10-11T06:05:48.459Z"),
   "request_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-10-11T06:05:48.459Z"),
   "sent_to_move_topic" : true,
   "send_attempt_timestamp" : ISODate("2017-10-11T06:05:48.459Z")
  }
 ]`

so I don't think "$sum": "$adjustments.change_in_quantity" is able to sum the elements in the array without an $unwind?

Comment: Replace the last `"$first"` with `"$sum"` and it should work.

Comment: ok, that worked! So that I understand what is going on here...the first "$sum": "$adjustments.change_in_quantity" will add all the elements (there can be multiple of these in the adjustments array) and add that as a field to each document returned by the previous $match stage. Then the $group stage's "adjusted_quantity": { "$sum": "$adjusted_quantity" }  will sum up the previously summed up "change_in_quantity" values of each document. Is this correct?